# TypeError: $.fn.yiiGridView.export is not a function?

Tags: php, csv, yii

I am getting the following error when I implement 
[Yii 1.1: Exporting CGridView results to CSV file](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/306/exporting-cgridview-results-to-csv-file/)

**Error message:**

> TypeError: $.fn.yiiGridView.export is not a function

```
$.fn.yiiGridView.export();
```

*Current Yii version: 1.1.10*

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: I just used that script http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/306/exporting cgridview-results-to-csv-file/. And followed same steps that they had mentioned.

Comment: Show all the code could you havenìt defined the relative function...